# Index of the element in array changes but value don't

Tags: arrays, c

could you please explain why the var ndx is changing every time, so do value (if use print function), but don't inside for loop, so every time I get the same value (2). And how can I fix that?

```
int PerfNum(int ww)
{
    int prime[20] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41};
    int ndx = 0;
        for (int base = 2; base <= sqrt(ww); base++) {
            for (int pw = prime[ndx]; ww >= pow(base, pw); ndx++) {  // expected value is in array
            //for (int pw = prime[ndx]; ww >= pow(base, prime[ndx]); pw++ ) { this one works but...
                if (ww == pow(base, pw)) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }

        }
        return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the the first part of the outer for statement you're initializing the variable pw. That occurs only one time (INITIALIZING) so incrementing that index won't result in any effects on the pw variable.

```
for(init operation <- occurs one time; condition <- occurs before every step; poststep operation <- occurs after every step )
```